# Reading variable length data in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have an input file that I cannot alter the format.  One of the lines in particular can contain either 6 or 7 reals and I don't have any way of knowing ahead of time.

After some reading, my understanding of the list-formatted read statement is that if I attempt to read 7 reals on a line containing 6, it will attempt to read from the next line.  The author of the code says that when it was written, it would read the 6 reals and then default the 7th to 0.  I am assuming he relied on some compiler specific behavior, because I cannot find a mention of this behavior anywhere.

I am using gfortran as my compiler, is there a way to specify this behavior?  Or is there a good way to count a number of inputs on a line and rewind to then chose to read the correct number?

Comment: You should show an actual example and the relevant piece of code. It ia very hard to realize what you are trying to describe in words.

Answer (score 4):

here is a little trick to accomplish that

```
 character*100 line
 real array(7)
 read(unit,'(a)')line  !read whole line as string'
 line=trim(line)//' 0' !add a zero to the string
 read(line,*)array  !list read
```

If the input line only had 6 values, the zero is now the seventh.
If there were seven to begin with it will do nothing.

I try to avoid using format specifiers on input as much as possible.

Comment: That seems like a neat trick, I will try it out.  You would think there would be a more canonical solution though.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use the `IOSTAT` statement for detecting the wrong format when you attempt to read 7 values when there are only 6. And you should use the `ADVANCE` statement to be able to retry to read the same line.

```
READ(LU,'7(F10.3)', IOSTAT=iError, ADVANCE='NO') MyArray(1:7)
IF(iError > 0) THEN
    ! Error when trying to read 7 values => try to read 6 !
    READ(LU, '6(F10.3)') MyArray(1:6)
ELSEIF(iError == 0) THEN
    READ(LU, *) ! For skipping the line read with success with 7 values
ENDIF
```

IOSTAT takes a negative value for example when you reach the end of the file, positive for problem of reading (typically formatting error) and 0 when the read succeed. See this link for a complete definition of gfortran error code: http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/samt/misc/gfortran_errors.html

Another way to do it could be to read the line as a string and manipulating the string in order to get the vector values :

```
CHARACTER(LEN=1000) :: sLine
...
READ(LU, '(A)') sLine
READ(sLine,'7(F10.3)', IOSTAT=iError) MyArray(1:7)
IF(iError > 0) THEN
    ! Error when trying to read 7 values => try to read 6 !
    READ(sLine, '6(F10.3)') MyArray(1:6)
ENDIF
```

If the values are written in fixed format, you can determine the lenght of the vector by testing the lenght of the line:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=1000) :: sLine
INTEGER :: nbValues
CHARACTER(LEN=2) :: sNbValues
...
READ(LU, '(A)') sLine
nbValues = LEN_TRIM(sLine) / 10 ! If format is like '(F10.x)'
WRITE(sNbValues, '(I2)') nbValues
READ(sLine, '('//TRIM(sNbValues)//'(F10.3))') MyArray(1:nbValues)
```

Comment: Does this actually prevent the read from wrapping to the next line and eating the first value?  It was my understanding that was the default behavior?

Comment: You're right my answer is wrong. I correct it immediately !